# Mocking a DateTime parameter input

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, mockito

Has anyone had issues supplying the `any` Mockito method to a `DateTime` mock method parameter? Basically I have this method implemented on the mock class `Future<int> testMethod(DateTime datetime)`.

So when I tried to stub the response on the test scenario through `when(mockClass.testMethod(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => 1)`, this shows always on IntelliJ line editor - `error: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'. (argument_type_not_assignable)`.

---

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

abstract class TestClass {
  Future<int> testMethod(DateTime dateTime);
}

class MockTestClass extends Mock implements TestClass {}

class InvokeClass {

  final TestClass testClass;

  InvokeClass(this.testClass);


}

// @GenerateMocks([InvokeClass, TestClass])
void main() {
  TestClass testClass = MockTestClass();
  InvokeClass invokeClass;

  setUp(() {
    testClass = MockTestClass();
    invokeClass = InvokeClass(testClass);
  });

  test('', () async {
    when(testClass.testMethod(any)).thenAnswer((_) => 1);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making the parameter Nullable so that the method becomes

```
testMethod(DateTime? datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the code generator from `mockito` 5.0.0: https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#lets-create-mocks

basically you would use:

```
abstract class MyClass {
  Future<int> testMethod(DateTime dateTime);
}

@GenerateMocks([MyClass])
void main() {
  final mock = MockMyClass();
  when(mock.testMethod(any)).....
}
```

the generator will create a method which takes a nullable DateTime, so `any` will work. see the [mockito documentation for more details](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#lets-create-mocks).

**Update**: giving your example it should look like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'testclass.mocks.dart'; // this will be generated by `build_runner build`

abstract class TestClass {
  Future<int> testMethod(DateTime dateTime);
}

class InvokeClass {

  final TestClass testClass;

  InvokeClass(this.testClass);


}

@GenerateMocks([TestClass])
void main() {
  MockTestClass testClass = MockTestClass();
  InvokeClass invokeClass;

  setUp(() {
    testClass = MockTestClass();
    invokeClass = InvokeClass(testClass);
  });

  test('', () async {
    when(testClass.testMethod(any)).thenAnswer((_) => 1);
  });
}
```

after those changes run `flutter run build_runner build` or `dart run build_runner build`.

Comment: Already using version `^5.0.11` and still having the same issue especially if the mock class is a dependency of the class in test.

Comment: @DavidB did you use the code generator? If so, how does the generated mock look like? I don't think the generator will create non-nullable method parameters.

Comment: @DavidB Maybe you should give more examples what you are experiencing.. You generate the mock classes with the build_runner, and create an instance of this mock in your test.. and pass this instance on to the class you want to test..

Comment: @DavidB 1. change `  TestClass testClass = MockTestClass();` to `final testClass = MockTestClass();` 2. remove the `class MockTestClass extends Mock implements TestClass` 3. add import statement: `import testclass.mocks.dart` 4. remove `// ` from @GenerateMocks 5. run `flutter pub run build_runner build`

Comment: @DavidB i've updated my answer with your example.